# Comment traduire « To be on fire » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions, expressions-idiomatiques, argot

En anglais, dans « *He is on fire today* » ou dans « *He has been on fire since yesterday* », l'expression « *to be on fire* » signifie que la personne est pleine d'énergie, et qu'elle fait des choses extraordinaires. Est-ce qu'il y a une expression similaire en français ?

---

He is on fire today or he's been on fire since yesterday. This means that he is charged and doing something great. What is a similar expression in French?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Populaire, oral : *à fond les manettes*, *au taquet* dans le sens : ne pas pouvoir faire mieux ou plus

Plus conventionnel : *occupé* dans un contexte normal dans le sens de *non disponible*, *surchargé* s'il s'agit d'une charge de travail très forte (comme *au taquet*)

**Intégration des remarques**

S'il s'agit de quelque chose d'important (familièrement de « grandiose ») :

- *Sous la lumière* s'il s'agit de sa position par rapport à un groupe,
- *Très en forme* ou *En pleine forme* si l'on considère son potentiel.

S'il s'agit de qualifier l'excellence d'un travail on pourrait dire « *Elle est sur le podium* », ou mieux encore « *Elle est sur la première marche du podium* » et donc la première, sous tous les regards.

Argot : « *Dis-donc, elle arrache aujourd'hui* » dans le sens ou elle porte vivement son action vers le haut, elle s'extrait brutalement de la moyenne.

Piège : « Elle est bonne aujourd'hui » s'entendra « Elle est [sexuellement] bonne. »

Comment: Je ne pense pas que "on fire" veuille dire ça - il s'agit plutôt de quelqu'un qui [accumule les succès en très peu de temps](http://www.phrasemix.com/englishphrases/man-youre-on-fire.html), ou qui en général [a une particulièrement bonne prestation](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/on+fire)

Comment: @Joubarc: *au taquet* s'en approche quand même pas mal, même si ça insinue que la « limite » est atteinte.

Answer (score 29):

Je préfère:

Il est *[déchaîné](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/d%C3%A9cha%C3%AEn%C3%A9/substantif)* aujourd'hui!

Ou, comme l'illustra Uderzo sur un scénario de Goscinny dans [*Astérix et les Goths*](http://www.asterix.com/edition/albums/asterix-et-les-goths.html) :
[image: Il est déchaîné !]

Comment: Dans cette optique : *Sous la lumière* s'il s'agit de sa position par rapport à un groupe, *[Très en|En pleine] forme* si l'on considère son potentiel. Argot : "Dis-donc, *elle arrache* aujourd'hui" dans le sens ou elle porte vivement son action vers le haut, elle s'extrait brutalement de la moyenne

Comment: Il est déchaîné !.. _Hi ! Hi ! Hi !_ Elle est amusante, celle-là !.. Je viens de la comprendre ! _Hi ! Hi ! Hi !_

Comment: @Stamm: Effectivement, _déchaîné_ a plusieurs sens ici :).

Answer (score 17):

Familièrement on peut aussi dire "*péter le feu*".

Comment: Il est *chaud comme la braise* !

Comment: I like this one as a translation of "He's on fire". Quite à propos!

Comment: ...et dans le même registre on entend parfois aussi *Il a le feu au cul !*

Answer (score 11):

À certains endroits, au Québec, nous traduisons simplement par:

- Il est en feu aujourd'hui!

Comment: Exactememt ce que j'allais répondre!

Comment: Et il a pas mal ? ;-)

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez - Pas plus que l'anglophone qui est "on fire". ;-)

Answer (score 7):

On dit très souvent (chez les moins de 40 ans):

> Il est bouillant.
>
> Il est chaud-bouillant.

En plus, ça garde l’idée de feu.

Sinon, on peut aussi dire:

> Il est au taquet.

Comment: "il est chaud du réchaud"

Answer (score 6):

[*Il (ou elle) a mangé du cheval*](http://www.larousse.com/en/dictionnaires/francais/cheval/15173/locution) would work in an informal context.

Another one, [*il pète le feu*](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/p%C3%A9ter_le_feu), perhaps more modern (and certainly closer to the English idea).

Comment: Tiens, ce n'est pas dans mon vocabulaire, et je n'aurais pas forcément compris si le contexte n'était pas clair.

Comment: @Gilles, je me demandais si c'était régional, mais c'est dans le Larousse après tout. Je ne l'utilise pas souvent, mais je l'ai déjà entendu.

Comment: jamais entendu "il a mangé du cheval", mais "du lion", oui. Il est pète le feu est assez courant aussi (en France)

Answer (score 4):

Je propose

- "il met tout son coeur"
- "il est à fond !" (familier)
- "il se défonce" (familier) (dans le sens mettre toute son énergie)
- "il met le turbo" (familier)
- "il met la gomme" (familier)

Answer (score 2):

On pourrait peut-être traduire par *être en veine*. Ce qui qualifie bien le côté réussite.

Answer (score 1):

> Depuis le debut de ce week-end, le pilote a la tête dans le guidon.

C'est le cas de le dire si cest une course de moto, mais cela représente aussi le fait de tout faire pour tirer le maximum de la situation.

Comment: Quand on a la tête dans le guidon, on a le nez sur l'asphalte et on ne voit rien de ce qui nous entoure, on est fort loin du podium

Comment: @cl-r do you even race ?

Comment: No sport ! En ces temps de tour de France je pensais au cyclisme.

Comment: Cyclisme racing has become a NO-sport, you got that right.

Answer (score 1):

Je dirai plutôt *il flambe!* (familier)

Answer (score 1):

Voici une autre possibilité du registre familier très courante :

> Il est chaud patate !

Answer (score 0):

Je pense que ce qui se rapproche le plus en français c'est "être en état de grâce"... Mais c'est un peu lourd. L'expression anglaise est plus passe-partout...

Comment: Pas du tout le même sens que l'expression anglaise.

Comment: Pourquoi vous pensez que cette expression rejoint celle en anglais ? C'eût été intéressant de vous comprendre. Merci.

Comment: @deLaDauversière Je crois que lorsque par exemple au tennis un joueur classé beaucoup moins bien que son adversaire obtient la victoire en réussissant à répétition des coups hallucinants et en ne ratant pratiquement rien, les commentateurs pourront avec raison dire qu'il est _«en état de grâce»_, ce qui indiquera plus ou moins la même réalité que celle désignées par d'autres qui diront que ce joueur _«is on fire»_.

Answer (score 0):

Dans le tennis on peut dire aussi qu'un joueur est en surchauffe

Comment: Hi and welcome to French Language SE. Could you please expand your answer by adding at least one example?